# git, how to remove a too large file from the "git add" list?

Tags: git, github

I'm working with git on Linux Ubuntu.
I accidentally added a file that is larger than 100 MB to my git, then committed, and then tried to push.
Here's the error I am getting:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': davidechicco
Password for 'https://davidechicco@github.com': 
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 304.05 MiB | 43.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 8), reused 16 (delta 5)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 3 local objects.
remote: warning: File temp/resultCollapseRows_datETcollapse_t_1381297037.RData is 71.73 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 9084702d401d9df326833f5eb38bdd6a
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File temp/combat_edata_fileName_1381297037.RData is 103.13 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File temp/mergedExpressionSets_1381297037.RData is 102.58 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/davidechicco/heart-failure-gene-expression-analysis.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/davidechicco/heart-failure-gene-expression-analysis.git'
```

Now I would like to say to git to stop trying to add the two files than are bigger than 100 MB. I tried many ways (`git reset filename`, `git rm --chached filename`, etc), but they never worked. What should I do?

Comment: You'll need some `filter-branch` "magic" here, arguably. Several questions here, try a search with the term.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git

Answer (score 0):

As your changes haven't been pushed to remote, you can try below steps.

1) Reset the last commit `git reset --hard HEAD^`. This will unstage the files.

2) Now exclude the large file and commit rest of them.

3) Push to remote.

Hope this helps!